# Concatenate values into multiple columns based on associated value

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Given a dataframe

```
+----+-------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|    |   Key | ID   | Status1   | Status2   | OrderID       |
|----+-------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------|
|  0 |     1 | A1   | False     | True      | 1234-USF-0025 |
|  1 |     1 | A1   | False     | True      | 1234-USF-0026 |
|  2 |     1 | A1   | False     | True      | 1234-USF-0027 |
|  3 |     2 | A1   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0025 |
|  4 |     2 | A1   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0026 |
|  5 |     2 | A1   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0027 |
|  6 |     3 | A1   | Anything  | True      | 1234-USF-0025 |
|  7 |     3 | A1   | False     | True      | 1234-USF-0026 |
|  8 |     3 | A1   | False     | Anything  | 1234-USF-0027 |
|  9 |     4 | A2   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0028 |
| 10 |     4 | A2   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0029 |
| 11 |     4 | A2   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0030 |
| 12 |     5 | A3   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0031 |
| 13 |     5 | A3   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0032 |
| 14 |     5 | A3   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0033 |
| 15 |     6 | A4   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0034 |
| 16 |     6 | A4   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0035 |
| 17 |     6 | A4   | True      | True      | 1234-USF-0036 |
+----+-------+------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
```

How can I transform to list each `OrderID` per `ID` and concatenate the `Key` based on each `Status`. If both `Stautses` are True, the concatenated `Keys` should go in the `TRUE` column. If either one is `Flase`, the `Keys` should go in the `FALSE` column. If either (or both) `Status` is anything but `True` or `False`, the `Key(s)` get concatenated in the `Other` column.

Desired Result df

```
Order ID        ID  TRUE    FALSE  OTHER
1234-USF-0025   A1   2       1       3
1234-USF-0026   A1   2       1,3
1234-USF-0027   A1   2       1       3
1234-USF-0028   A2   4  
1234-USF-0029   A2   4  
1234-USF-0030   A2   4  
1234-USF-0031   A3   5  
1234-USF-0032   A3   5  
1234-USF-0033   A3   5  
1234-USF-0034   A4   6  
1234-USF-0035   A4   6  
1234-USF-0036   A4   6
```

**What I've tried**

`df = df.groupby(['OrderID','ID'])['Key'].apply(','.join).reset_index()`

```
+----+---------------+------+-------+
|    | OrderID       | ID   | Key   |
|----+---------------+------+-------|
|  0 | 1234-USF-0025 | A1   | 1,2,3 |
|  1 | 1234-USF-0026 | A1   | 1,2,3 |
|  2 | 1234-USF-0027 | A1   | 1,2,3 |
|  3 | 1234-USF-0028 | A2   | 4     |
|  4 | 1234-USF-0029 | A2   | 4     |
|  5 | 1234-USF-0030 | A2   | 4     |
|  6 | 1234-USF-0031 | A3   | 5     |
|  7 | 1234-USF-0032 | A3   | 5     |
|  8 | 1234-USF-0033 | A3   | 5     |
|  9 | 1234-USF-0034 | A4   | 6     |
| 10 | 1234-USF-0035 | A4   | 6     |
| 11 | 1234-USF-0036 | A4   | 6     |
+----+---------------+------+-------+
```

The above certainly gets me close, but I'm not sure how to break out the `Keys` into their respective columns (`TRUE`, `FALSE` and `OTHER`)

**Notes**

I previously converted the `Key` column to string

`Order IDs` can be duplicated for `IDs`, but will have different `Keys`

Comment: I can help but I am confused what you want the final result to look like.  Can you show what you want the dataframe to look like? Because you have two statuses for each key and can have multiples keys per Order ID I dont understand what you want your frame to look like.

Comment: @Error - Syntactical Remorse, I edited my question to be more clear, namely...If both `Stautses` are `True`, the concatenated `Keys` should go in the `TRUE` column. If either one is `Flase`, the `Keys` should go in the `FALSE` column. If either (or both) `Status` is anything but `True` or `False`, the `Key(s)` get concatenated in the `Other` column.

Comment: So you don't want the Key column at all you want a True False and Other column?

Comment: Yes, the Key column is parsed out into either the `TRUE`, `FALSE` or `OTHER` column.

Comment: Last clarity question: is the "True " booleans or strings in the dataframe?

Comment: Strings...good question and thanks for teasing this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working solution but there is most definitely a faster and cleaner way to do it.  First I add a column for your Boolean logic, then I do your `groupby` to condense the table, then I go through and populate the `True`, `False`, and `Other` columns using the `Key` and `Result` columns.  Finally I remove the unneeded columns and aggregate the rows.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# Your dataframe for testing purposes
df = pd.DataFrame({'Key': '1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 5 5 5 6 6 6'.split(),
                   'ID': 'A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A1 A2 A2 A2 A3 A3 A3 A4 A4 A4'.split(),
                   'Status1': 'False False False True True True Anything False False True True True True True True True True True'.split(),
                   'Status2': 'True True True True True True True True Anything True True True True True True True True True'.split(),
                   'OrderID': '25 26 27 25 26 27 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36'.split()})



# First we need to do this boolean logic
df["Result"] = ""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  stat1 = row["Status1"]
  stat2 = row["Status2"]

  if stat1 == "True" and stat2 == "True":
    row["Result"] = "True"
  elif stat1 == "False" and stat2 == "False" or stat1 == "True" and stat2 == "False" or stat1 == "False" and stat2 == "True":
    row["Result"] = "False"
  else:
    row["Result"] = "Other"


# Now we do your group by
df = df.groupby(['OrderID','ID', 'Result'])['Key'].apply(','.join).reset_index()


# Now we populate the columns you wanted populated
df["True"] = ""
df["False"] = ""
df["Other"] = ""
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  if row[row["Result"]]:
    row[row["Result"]] += "," + row["Key"]
  else:
    row[row["Result"]] += row["Key"]
del df['Result']
del df['Key']


# Final we aggregate the rows to flatten it.
df = df.groupby(['OrderID','ID'], as_index=False).agg(lambda x: "%s" % ''.join(x))
```

Comment: Got a working solution (tested). Ill update my answer.